# No show pages inside frameset

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my spring boot application I use frameset.

Here index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<frameset cols="15%,*">
    <frame src="navigator.html" name="navigator" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frame src="welcome.html" name="welcome">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Here `IndexController.java`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeContoller {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

NavigatorContoller.java

```
@Controller
public class NavigatorController {

    @GetMapping("/navigator")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "navigator";
    }
}
```

Here security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; // get by Spring

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Here, you are making the public directory on the classpath root available without authentication (e..g. for css files)
                .antMatchers("/public/**", "/registration.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/index"))
                .failureUrl("/login-error.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll();
    }
```

welcome.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to <span th:text="${appName}">Our App</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

navigator.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<p><a href="/users">Users</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- By default logout is only triggered with a POST request to "/logout" -->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when open index.html the frame is show, but pages inside frames not show (`welcome.html, navigator.html`) not show. Just message:

```
localhost refused to connect.
```

[image]

Comment: try putting the full URL with localhost in the frame instead of just the name of the file

Comment: @Dylan not help. Same result

Comment: @Dylan When I turn off SecurityConfiguration.java then pages success open. So I need to correct config security policy.

Comment: @Dylan In security config, this help: .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()